# Trying to get a better understanding of SelectedValuePath and IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following XAML produces a run-time Binding error when I click on an item in the `ListBox`:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="strings" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>one</sys:String>
            <sys:String>two</sys:String>
            <sys:String>three</sys:String>
            <sys:String>four</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox
            DataContext="{StaticResource strings}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            SelectedValuePath="{Binding /Length}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- Row 0 -->
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">String:</Label>
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{Binding}"/>
                        <!-- Row 1 -->
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Length:</Label>
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{Binding Length, Mode=Default}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the run-time Binding error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: '3' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1191344027)'. BindingExpression:Path=3; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1191344027); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

I would like the selected value of the `ListBox` to be the Length of the selected `String` object. What is wrong with my `SelectedValuePath` Binding syntax? Are there any related issues with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

Replace

```
SelectedValuePath="{Binding /Length}"
```

with

```
SelectedValuePath="Length"
```

**Long answer**

SelectedValuePath is a string that gives the path from an object to the selected value.  By writing `SelectedValuePath="{Binding /Length}"` you are binding **SelectedValuePath** (not **SeletedValue**) to the "Length" property of the selected item, so if the length of the selected item is 3 then the value of the **SelectedValuePath** property is set to the string "3".  Then WPF tries to compute **SelectedValue** by finding a property named "3" on the string.  Since the string object doesn't have a property named "3" you get the error.

You might think that `SelectedValue={Binding /Length}"` would do the trick, and indeed it does express the concept of what you are actually trying to do.  But it does not actually work because `Selector` has code that overwrites `SelectedValue` whenever `SelectedItem` changes.

Another way to look at this is that setting `SelecteValuePath` to the value "abcd" is effectively equivalent to setting `SelectedValue` to `"{Binding /abcd}"` (but only if IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true").